# nodeos won't run properly, gives time error (Ubuntu 16.04 VM)

Tags: nodeos

This is what I get in my console when I run nodeos, this is on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM:

```
sunny@sunny-VirtualBox:~$ nodeos
3488600ms thread-0 chain_plugin.cpp:125 plugin_initialize ] initializing chain plugin
3488600ms thread-0 main.cpp:99 main ] 13 N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_9gregorian8bad_yearEEEEE: Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000
Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000: unable to convert ISO-formatted string to fc::time_point_sec
{"what":"Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000"}
thread-0 time.cpp:44 from_iso_string
unable to convert ISO-formatted string to fc::time_point
{}
thread-0 time.cpp:64 from_iso_string
```

I built EOS properly and did sudo make install in the /build folder. What else should I try?